# Two different classes with random values have the same output

Tags: class, processing

I am making the Bouncing Ball using **Processing**. It works fine when I use the ball object once, but when I use it twice like `ball1 & ball2`, the balls appear on  top of each other making the delusion that it is just one ball bouncing, although I'm setting their primary location and velocity a random number. So, where is the problem? (first argument is for velocity and the second is for x Coordinate)
Main class:

```cs
Ball ball1 = new Ball(int(random(0, 2)),int(random(width)));
Ball ball2 = new Ball(int(random(0, 2)),int(random(width)));

void setup() {
  // Windows configurations
  size(640, 360);
  background(50);
}

void draw() {
  // Draw the circle
  ball1.display();
  // Circle movements
  ball1.movements();
  // Movement limits
  ball1.movementLimits();

  // Draw the circle
  ball2.display();
  // Circle movements
  ball2.movements();
  // Movement limits
  ball2.movementLimits();
}
```

Ball class:

```cs
float xCoordinates;
float yCoordinates;
float xVelocity;
float yVelocity;
final float gravity = 0.1;

class Ball {

  Ball(int Velocity, int Coordinates) {
    xCoordinates = Coordinates;
    yCoordinates = height / 6;

    if (Velocity == 0)
      xVelocity = 2;
    else
      xVelocity = -2;

    if (Velocity == 0)
      yVelocity = 2;
    else
      yVelocity = -2;
  }

  void movementLimits() {
    if (xCoordinates - 10 <= 0 || xCoordinates + 10 >= width)
      xVelocity *= -1;
    if (yCoordinates + 10 >= height)
      yVelocity *= -0.9;
    if (yCoordinates - 10 <= 0)
      yVelocity *= -1;
  }

  void movements() {
    xCoordinates += xVelocity;
    yCoordinates += yVelocity;
    yVelocity += gravity;
  }

  void display() {
    background(50);
    fill(255);
    stroke(255);
    circle(xCoordinates, yCoordinates, 20);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Problem 1:

Both of your objects are shaing the same cooridinates and velocity. They are stored globally so when one object changes it, the change is used by the other object as well. To fix this you should give your Ball class properties to hold the coordinates and velocities.

```
class Ball{
   float x;
   float y;
   float dx;
   float dy

   public Ball(float x, float y, float dx, float dy){
      this.x = x;
      this.y = y;
      this.dx = dx;
      this.dy = dy;
   }
}
```

#### Problem 2:

In the display function in Ball, you call `background(50);`. This will basicly cover the entire screan with the new background; over any previous balls which includes ball1. However, if you remove this line you'll get a kind of cool effect cause by all previous ball drawing sticking around. You should move the `background(50);` line to the beginning of the draw function. This way, you draw the two balls, draw over them with gray, then redraw the two balls in their new positions.

Comment: I moved the variables inside the class, but nothing changes. Even when I print each ball's velocity and X coordinate, they are different.

Comment: While my answer was a cause of seeing just one ball, I discovered that you also are redrawing the background every display. This covers up all previous thing that were drawn in that draw loop. I'll update my answer

Comment: You are right, the logic is correct, but I should not write the `background(50)` in the Ball class. So, I solved the problem by writing the command in the draw function in the main class.